# Webpack, including HTML files within other HTML files

Tags: webpack, pug

Webpack and Pug have a really nifty feature called [includes](https://pugjs.org/language/includes.html). This allows you to load another pug template from a pug template by just calling:

```
  include ../components/head.pug
```

As far as I understand it this doesn't use any JS and is done automatically when Webpack compiles the scripts.

Is there any way to achieve this without using pug and **without** adding HTML files to the dom client-side with JS?

I've looked at a bunch of Webpack plugins but none seem to do this without loading html from the JS.

Comment: This is a Pug feature, not a Webpack feature. And it does use javascript, albeit server-side node javascript. That's what powers Webpack.

Comment: @Sean Of course this is a Pug feature, that's why I asked if something similar existed to achieve without Pug. I specifically mention that I don't need a JS solution that loads content client-side, I don't know how you could misunderstand it. Either way the question is solved, thanks for the helpful comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is included in [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin).

Just add:

```
  <%= require('html-loader!../components/file.html') %>
```

Within the html file and it will be automatically replaced on compile.